# Выполненине застывает после ввода слов

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbopascal

Задание:

> Вывести все слова, отличающиеся от последнего слова, в которых первая буква последнего  слова  встречается еще раз.

В Turbo Pascal 7 выполненине застывает после ввода слов. Хоть и в онлайн компиляторе Turbo Pascal (на http://rextester.com) все работает отлично. В чем может быть причина?

```
uses crt;

const nmax=100;

type m=array [1..nmax] of string;

var i:byte;
    s:string;
    p:integer;
    A:m;

{Ввод предложения}
Procedure vvodstroki(var st:string);
begin
  Writeln('Введите предложение: ');
  readln(st);
  st:=st+concat(' ');
end;

{подсчёт кол-ва слов для ввода в массив}
Procedure kol_slov(st:string; var k:integer);
begin
  k:=0;
  repeat
    for i:=1 to length(st) do
    if st[i] = ' ' then
      k:=k+1;
  until k in [1..nmax];
end;

Begin
  clrscr;

  vvodstroki(s);
  kol_slov(s,p);

  {запись слов в массив}
  for i:=1 to p  do
  begin
     A[i]:=copy(s,1,pos(' ',s)-1);
     delete(s,1,pos(' ',s));
   end;
  {Слова отличные от последнего слова, в которые первая буква входит еще раз.}

  writeln('Slova otlichnie ot poslednego slova, v kotorie pervaya bukva vhodit eshe raz:');
  for i:= 1 to p-1 do 
    if ((A[i]<>A[p]) And (copy(A[i],1,1) = copy(A[p],1,1))) Then

  writeln(A[i]); 

  readkey;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if st[i] = ' ' then
  k:=k+1;
until k in [1..nmax];
```

Ну у тебя же всегда k в этом диапазоне, вот и зацикливание

Comment: Только при пробелах k инкрементиться будет

Comment: на счет инкриметна k только при пробелах понятно, но я так понял онлайн компилятор зацикливание сам как-то отрубал , поэтому в нем работало а в середе Turbo Pascal 7 не рабоатет, но как  мне решить проблему с тем чтобы не зацикливалось? но и подсчитывало днамически.